# Is there way to join has many relation tables and get aggregate on multiple columns based on type

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables interviews and ratings with following data

```
Interviews Table
+--------------+-----------+
| interview_id | Candidate |
+--------------+-----------+
|            1 | Ram       |
|            2 | Rahim     |
|            3 | Joseph    |
+--------------+-----------+
Ratings Table
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+--------------+
| rating_id | rating | skill | skill_type | interview_id |
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+--------------+
|         1 |      3 | Java  | Required   |            1 |
|         2 |      4 | C     | Optional   |            1 |
|         3 |      5 | MySQL | Required   |            1 |
|         4 |      3 | HTML  | Optional   |            1 |
|         5 |      5 | Java  | Required   |            2 |
|         6 |      2 | C     | Optional   |            2 |
|         7 |      4 | MySQL | Required   |            2 |
|         8 |      1 | HTML  | Optional   |            2 |
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+--------------+
```

I was trying to fetch average rating for candidates per skill type
in format

```
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Candidate | Required Rating | Optional Rating |
+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

This SQL

```
Select i.candidate, r.rating, r.skill, r.skill_type 
from interviews i, ratings r 
where r.interview_id = i.interview_id;
```

gives me

```
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
| candidate | rating | skill | skill_type |
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
| Ram       |      3 | Java  | Required   |
| Ram       |      4 | C     | Optional   |
| Ram       |      5 | MySQL | Required   |
| Ram       |      3 | HTML  | Optional   |
| Rahim     |      5 | Java  | Required   |
| Rahim     |      2 | C     | Optional   |
| Rahim     |      4 | MySQL | Required   |
| Rahim     |      1 | HTML  | Optional   |
+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

I stuck here to fetch aggregate based on skill type for each candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the results you want, taking the average based on the value of `skill_type` in the `ratings` table:

```
SELECT i.Candidate, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.skill_type = 'Required' THEN rating END) AS `Required Rating`,
       AVG(CASE WHEN r.skill_type = 'Optional' THEN rating END) AS `Optional Rating`
FROM interviews i
JOIN ratings r
ON r.interview_id = i.interview_id
GROUP BY i.Candidate
```

Output:

```
Candidate   Required Rating Optional Rating
Rahim       4.5             1.5
Ram         4               3.5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fxFi5RZK3i2WMuo7fiAGLz/0)

Comment: Can you please look into this, am trying hard to find a solution. @nick https://stackoverflow.com/q/57890951/2362637